# OMG I accidentally posted my question to the wrong place so now it is marked "Closed. This question is off-topic." How do I move it & apologize!

Tags: support, halacha

My original question was (and still is):
Lighting Shabbat candles is a holy obligation for me. Have a scheduling conflict w-leading services for Seniors @ an assisted living facility. HELP! [closed]

I noticed "things look different" ... but was more concerned about seeking advice re: my question since my rabbi is away.

I want to remove/move my query here, where it obviously belongs, from there where it obviously does not belong and apologize for my blunder.

Though my first inclination is: I can figure this on my own! I've also seen how that can exacerbate things and really irritate people. How do I make this right?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

[Where you asked it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132982/170) is no worse than "here". The problem, as explained in the "off-topic" notice's fine print, is that

> [q]uestions asking for a practical ruling (p'sak halacha) are off-topic. For practical advice [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).